# Sync files between 2 or more s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a production s3 bucket which have more then 80 + GB of files. I want to sync this bucket with another bucket which will act as a back up bucket with limited access. I cant use Glacier for backing up because of the time taken for AWS to restore the images back. I have to sync with another bucket, initially I was running s3cmd sync in a large ec2 instance to make sure the buckets are in-sync. But its becoming a costly operation and instance is timing out because of lack of memory. Is there any way to sync multiple buckets with out using s3cmd and which is reliable.

Kindly let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have used [CloudBerry Explorer](http://cloudberrylab.com/) for syncing data among buckets, its pretty awesome and transfer is free for buckets in one Geographical location.